# How can I create a views with right-join relationship?

Tags: views

I would like to create a view with a relationship between 2 tables, where the relationship must perform right-join instead of inner join.
How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are getting at, but you might need to switch the chain around and start from the rightmost table and left join by not ticking the "this relationship is required".